# Chrome browser - DotNetNuke popup moves to top of screen and cannot close it

Tags: google-chrome, dotnetnuke, modalpopup

I have created a dnnModal popup in DotNetNuke that works very nicely, except in the Chrome browser when the anchor tag is clicked that is in the form to move down the page, the entire popup moves up to the top of the screen so that the close button is not available to close the popup window. This would not work well for viewers.

Can someone please help me with a workaround for this problem? I'm a very new programmer, a beginner, and need help in figuring out what to do. Javascript Close Window does not work in this iframe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have the inspector / web developer tools in Chrome open sometimes this happens.

Answer (score 0):

This typically occurs when you have a skin that isn't using XHTML or HTML doctypes. I would start by looking at your skin to see what the cause might be.

I have a free opensource skin for DNN http://multifunction.codeplex.com/ that should work with DNN 7.0.2+